# How can I draw something on top of AVPlayer video in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview, avplayer

In my app I want to be able to draw rectangles on top of the playing video. I already implemented the drawing canvas which is a NSView, and I have a player implemented as well.

However, when I place my drawing canvas on top of my player view, player view is still showing up on **top**.

I was thinking that my drawing canvas wasn't on top of the player view, but it is. When I change the size of the window, I can see that on the area of the window that is not covered by the video I can draw. However, magically my drawing is not showing up on top of the playing video.

I really don't know where to find the problem.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution for iOS, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932921/1167833), and it works in OS X too (I tested on OS X 10.10.2).

Basically, set the `zPosition` of the view you want on top:

```
 topView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

i also had a problem where one NSView that i add to a superView was layer backed and the last NSView wasn't, and always the layer backed NSView would be on top, so i'd recommend you to enable the layer for any NSView that would come on top of the AVPlayer,
[yourCanvasView setWantsLayer : YES];

...
i think this would do the job,

Comment: that is not the problem...that stuff is set up properly

Comment: @EugeneGordin this answer is probably the right one. At least it helps. I don't know another way to make video showing in the view except `setWantsLayer : YES`, and it makes this layer the top layer, as I got it right. And we must set same thing to buttons to see they over the video layer. I'll try to find another way, this works but doesn't look like a proper one.

Comment: I have the same problem (in my case I want to put an NSButton over my AVPlayerView), and setting wantsLayer on either or both of my views made no difference whatsoever. Any other ideas?

Comment: This worked for me, too. I didn't have to change the Z-order, enabling the layer did the trick.

Comment: I am facing the same problem: `AVPlayerView` added as subview is always displayed on top. Setting `.wantsLayer` to `true` on all the other views had no effect.